# can I add div before elements which be added dynamically in future?

Tags: jquery

I have a drag drop elements facility. I want to add a div before any element, after it is dropped to the page. Is it possible ?
I tried to do it using live, but number divs it adds are strange. For first time, it add one or two and second time. it adds more than two.
I'm trying this :

```
$('#PageContent > .textElementClass').live('dblclick', function(e) {
ElementWidth=$(e.target).width();
targetElement=$(e.target);
$(e.target).css({'display':'none'});
$(e.target).before('<div id="TextValue" style="'+ElementWidth+'"><textarea cols="50" rows="10">Edit Content</textarea><input type="button" value="Save" class="SaveContent"></div>');

$('.SaveContent').live('click', function(e){
 firstChild=$('#TextValue > textarea').html();
 $(targetElement).html(firstChild);
 $(targetElement).css({'display':'block'});
 $('#TextValue').remove();
});
   });
```

Comment: Care to put it up on jsFiddle? I can't test :s

Answer (score 1):

You need a few changes here, first is that IDs can't be used more than once in a page, so if you're dynamically adding something, it shouldn't include the same ID like you have with this:

```
<div id="TextValue">
```

But, you don't need an ID, you can simply fire the `<textarea>` that's in the `<div>` you clicked using [tree-traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) to find it relative to what you clicked on, like this:

```
$(this).siblings("textarea").val();
```

This also uses [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value, use this instead of  [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).  Also, you can use [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) instead of setting the [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) manually.

When you're setting the style, it's ending up as `style="40"`, which is invalid/has no effect...the `<div>` should stretch to the proper width, so I removed this piece.  If it's needed, you can add it back via [`.width(valueToSet)`](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

Last, you can use `this` in a [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler and your `.live('click',...)` should be **outside** your `.live('dblclick',...)`, otherwise it's adding an *additional* save click handler every time you add an element, resulting in an additional save and remove each time.

Overall, it should look more like this:

```
$('#PageContent > .textElementClass').live('dblclick', function() {
  targetElement = $(this).hide()
                         .before('<div><textarea cols="50" rows="10">Edit Content</textarea><input type="button" value="Save" class="SaveContent"></div>');
});
$('.SaveContent').live('click', function(){
  var ta = $(this).siblings("textarea").remove();
  $(targetElement).html(ta.val()).show();
});
```